# Typemock Auto-Deploy and Build Definition Errors

Tags: build, typemock

I'm hoping there are some Typemock guru's which can help with the following error.

We’re currently testing Typemock’s (v7.0.6) auto-deploy feature as part of a TFS 2010 build. One issue I’d like to resolve is the following error, which occurs when creating or editing a build definition:

```
Summary: There were 0 failures, 2 errors and 0 warnings loading custom activities and services.

Error: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\gmonk\AppData\Local\Temp\VSTFSBuild\a6c25fba-a63b-4b51-92de-db3a3f60dcd0\MockWeaver.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Error: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\gmonk\AppData\Local\Temp\VSTFSBuild\a6c25fba-a63b-4b51-92de-db3a3f60dcd0\ProfileLinker.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
```

I don't have in-depth knowledge, but from what I understand, when you create, or edit a build definition, all assemblies in the CustomBuildActivities directory are transferred to your local machine and loaded by Visual Studio(?).

#### Further Info

This error appears in the Visual Studio Output window on every client, regardless if Typemock is installed on their machine or not. Note the path in the error does actually exist on the local machine and that all files are there.

The path to our custom assemblies is “C:\TFS\Global\CustomBuildActivities”

The server path is “$/Global/CustomBuildActivities”

The following files are present and checked-in within these directories:

- TypeMock.Configuration.exe
- Configuration.dll
- Typemock.ArrangeActAssert.dll
- TypeMock.CLI.Common.dll
- TypeMock.dll
- TypeMock.Integration.dll
- Typemock.Interceptors.dll
- Typemock.Isolator.VisualBasic.dll
- TypeMock.TFS2010.dll
- blacklist.dat
- exclude.dat
- namespaces.dat
- typemockconfig.xml
- MockWeaver.dll *
- ProfileLinker.dll *

*At the time of typing this – these files are from the x64 directory from my local installation of Typemock. I’ve also tried the x86 versions and both versions within their respective directories.

The build server is Windows Server 2008 64 bit, developer machines are Windows 7 32 bit.

The TFS build controller is set up to look for custom assemblies in “$/Global/CustomBuildActivities” (i.e. the “Version control path to custom assemblies”)

Typemock is not installed on the server.

The build template (XAML), has the relevant Typemock build activities as per the [documentation](http://docs.typemock.com/isolator/Default.aspx##typemock.chm/Documentation/TFSBuild.html). (We’re using TypemockRegister/Start/Stop, and these activities can be seen in the build log generating no errors). However, the errors shown above still appear when the build template doesn’t have the Typemock activities.

Answer (score 1):

I think I had the same issue but all you need to do is that you need to register those dll.

1. open up your visual stdio command prompt from Visual Studio Tools under Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.
2. type `regsvc32 "C:\Program files\Typemock\Isolator\7\AutoDeploy\x64\ProfileLink.dll"`
   or `regsvc32 "C:\Program files\Typemock\Isolator\7\AutoDeploy\x64\MockWeaver.dll"`

The issue went away.